# Query the state of 'COMPATIBILITY_MODE' ON / OFF from another session in ASE

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, embedded-sql

As of Sybase ASE 15.0.3 one can set the so called `COMPATIBILITY_MODE` within a session to `ON` or `OFF` with the SQL or ESQL/C command:

```
SQL SET COMPATIBILITY_MODE ON
```

This can be configured too as server wide option, but this is not meant here.

The question is, if one can query **from another session**, for example with SQL, the actual value of a given session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, for a given SPID, check the SUID of the process and run:

```
dbcc traceon(3604)
go
dbcc pss(@suid, @spid)
go
```

In the output you have for example:

```
...
poptions=7 (OPT_TRUNCABORT) 8 (OPT_ARITHABORT) 40 (OPT_PREFETCH) 
41 (OPT_TRIGGERS) 42 (OPT_REPLICATION_1) 43 (OPT_REPLICATION_2) 
48 (OPT_TRANSRPC) 58 (OPT_REMOTE_INDEXES) 62 (OPT_STMT_CACHE) 
64 (OPT_PROC_RETURN_STATUS) 65 (OPT_PROC_OUTPUT_PARAMS) 
84 (OPT_LITERAL_AUTOPARAM) 93 (OPT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE) 
107 (OPT_FDP_CURRENCY) 
...
```

The flag *OPT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE* indicates that this session has compatiblity mode turned on.